# NSURL.absoluteString returns malformed filepath

Tags: macos, nsurl

As part of testing my MacOS Document-based Swift app, I'm logging a URL with:

```
 NSLog(url.absoluteString)
```

If that URL has spaces, I get crazy results, like:

```
file:///Users/Ben/Desktop/Test            0.000000older/Lotti2issa(null)apientiae220Basso                   ontinuo2ooklet.pdf
```

Tha actual filepath is:

```
/Users/Ben/Desktop/Test folder/Lotti Missa Sapientiae - Basso continuo booklet.pdf
```

Is this just some formatting issue with absoluteString, or is a problem with my URL?

I'm not generating the URL myself: the value is coming in from AppKit, as it's the parameter in a function of NSDocument that I'm overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path of a file system URL use **always** the `path` API.

```
NSLog(url.path)
```

`absoluteString` returns a percent escaped URL string including the `scheme` (`file://`, `https//` etc.) and the `host` which is irrelevant in the file system.